# How to load contents immediately when finished in its INDEX regardless if the loop is still iterating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I'm trying to append data form inside a for loop to a list of panels **asynchronously**.

**Expected behavior:** 
If the first loop finishes appending data to the panel, the panel should appear and not wait for the whole loop to finish and show all the panel list.

the starting HTML:

```
<ul id="list_handler" class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
        <div id="title" class="collapsible-header">First</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS loop:

```
theList = main_content.find("ul#list_handler");

$.each(dataList, function(index, data) {

    if (index >= 1) {
        listPanel= theList.children(":first").clone();
    } else {
        listPanel= theList.children(":first");
    }

    // $(listPanel).fadeIn("fast").promise().done(function(){
    //  listPanel.find("#title").html(data.title);
    //  theList.append(listPanel);
    // });
    // this solution did not work

    listPanel.find("#title").html(data.title);
    theList.append(listPanel);

});
```

EXPECTED RESULT

```
index = 0:
datatitle_1

index = 1:
datatitle_1
datatitle_2

index = 2:
datatitle_1
datatitle_2
datatitle_3
```

CURRENT RESULT

```
index = 0:

index = 1:

index = 2:
datatitle_1
datatitle_2
datatitle_3
```

Was my question clear? I think I can do this with jQuery's ajax but I have no idea how.

Comment: I think you're misusing the term asynchronous.  It doesn't appear that you have any async operations in your code. Is what you really want to do is to just have progressive display so that each result is displayed immediately rather than waiting for the whole loop to finish before anything is displayed?  If so, you should state the problem as that and leave an asynchronous solution out of the problem statement.

Comment: but isnt that what asynchronous is? to not wait for other operation to finish and display the data immediately when done? but yes! thats my problem. any ideas? @jfriend00

Comment: It just works a lot better here on stackoverflow if you describe what you're trying to achieve in your question rather than describe what you think is the solution.  I'd suggest you edit your question to say that the problem you're trying to solve is immediately display of each successive result in your loop and stop assuming/describing your guess at a solution.

Comment: async comes in play when loading data from REST for example. Here there is only a sync loop (the `for`) that need to append data every iteration and not only at the end of that loop. pls edit question.